# Word Online needs to be restarted when using insertInlinePictureFromBase64 after insertText

Tags: office-js

I am trying to insert mixed content (text + image ) into a document using the Word JS API. This works fine in Word 2016.

In Word Online the content is inserted as well but afterwards a generic error message is displayed stating Word has to be restarted. After the reload the inserted data is sometimes intact, sometimes the text or image is missing.

Here is the code I used to reproduce the problem:

```
Word.run(function (ctx) {
    var selectedRange = ctx.document.getSelection();

    selectedRange.insertText("test", "End");
    selectedRange.insertInlinePictureFromBase64("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAIAAAAC64paAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMjCGJ1kDAAAATUlEQVQ4T8XLsQ3AMADDsPz/dDqIB7hTOArQee3+ZIs2s0Wb2aLNbNFmtmgzW7SZLdrMFm1mizazRZvZos1s0Wa2aDNbtJkt2sz2yDkfSZX9H3ywdoMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=", "End");
    selectedRange.select("End");

    return ctx.sync();
  });
```

Further observations:

- The error occurs only when the document is empty
- Inserting the image first and then the text works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug of the API implementation, we are actively working on the fix. As you said, you can first insert the picture and then the text to act as a temp workaround.